# Задачка на Python: Формат ввода Одно натуральное число N, Формат вывода N строк с фразой: "Купи слона!"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не обессудьте) Только захожу в программирование. Начал практикум от Яндекса. Там такая задачка. К слову это самое начало - соответственно решение какое-то супербанальное. Без условий и каких-то замысловатых функций.
Везде пишут как на Python выводить на разных строках через последовательные команды print на разных строках, через f строку, через множественные кавычки, и через \n.

Но тут, по идее, разумеется, нужно сначала ввести число, следовательно

1. int(input())
2. ....

а вот дальше как его разнести по n строкам хз.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть в сторону циклов на питоне. Вот отлично в документации все написано https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Благодарю! Но скорее всего нет, так как это одна из 20 задачек для закрепления темы "2.1. Ввод и вывод данных. Операции с числами, строками. Форматирование". 
"Циклы" будут только через одну тему - пункт 2.3

Comment: Ммм, ну тогда можно попробовать print('Купи слона\n' * N)

Comment: Работает!!!)) Блин, я вокруг да около бродил. С синтаксисом ошибался. Огромное благодарю!)

Comment: Без проблем! Вам также ответили внизу. Если вас устраивает ответ стоит отметить ответ на вопрос как правильный. И все-таки лучше стараться решать задачи самому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, банальное решение без циклов есть:

```
n = int(input())
res = 'Купи слона\n' * n

print(res)
```

Comment: Но я бы советовал решать задачки самостоятельно, иначе обучение будет нерезультативным